# podspec JSQMessagesViewController non-modular header

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I want to use `JSQMessagesViewController` as a dependency to my swift pod. When I build my example app I get the old non-modular header error related to the `JSQSystemSoundPlayer` but I don't know how to get around it with `XCode 7`.

**Podspec**:

```
s.dependency 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer'
s.dependency 'JSQMessagesViewController', '7.2.0' #Also tried 5.3.2
```

Errors:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have downloaded example app and it builds. Xcode version: 7.2.1. Also tried to use it as a dependency view Cocoa Pods "pod 'JSQSystemSoundPlayer'" still works. Did you change something in the  project file?

Comment: no I'm not consuming JSQMessagesViewController in any app. I meant my pod example app. I'm creating a pod and JSQMessagesViewController is a dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with `v7.2.0` of JSQMessagesViewController: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/pull/1284

Check this pull-request: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/pull/1284

Specifically, this comment from jessesquires (the author): https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/pull/1284#issuecomment-181132880

The fix will be part of `v7.2.1` according to that thread.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to `JSQSystemSoundPlayer`.
Add this at the beginning of your `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
```

So app will use frameworks instead of static libraries for the included projects.

Summary of changes to JSQMessagesViewController:

1. Change Podfile platform to iOS 8 (`platform :ios, '8.0'`)
2. Change Podfile to use frameworks instead of static libraries (`use_frameworks!`)
3. Change project structure deployment target to iOS 8
4. Run pod install
5. Build & run the app

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Swift doesn't play nice with importing non-modular frameworks into frameworks. Essentially, you will only run into this problem when bundling a framework inside another. There is a simple solution, however it requires some work JSQSystemSoundPlayer as well as JSQMessagesViewController. Both projects will need to have the following Xcode project setting: DEFINES_MODULE = YES.

Comment: inside JSQSystemSoundPlayer+JSQMessages.h change #import <JSQSystemSoundPlayer/JSQSystemSoundPlayer.h>
to @import JSQSystemSoundPlayer; This should fix the issue until v7.2.0 comes out as metioned by pshah below.